# Android : Download images from server in real size

Tags: android

I'm downloading images from server and store it in my internal_storage folder.But the downloaded image size is **(Width 800 * Height 534)** in pixel and internal_storage image size is **(Width 400 * Height 267)**. Why not stored the image size is **(Width 800 * Height 534)** in pixel in real size.

Here is my code for download images from server

```
str_DownLoadUrl = "http://103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/3_20150928162252018.png";

 download_PngFile(str_DownLoadUrl);

    void download_PngFile(String fileUrl) {

            try {
                URL ImgUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) ImgUrl.openConnection();
                conn.connect();

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 2;
                Bitmap imagenObtenida = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream(), null, options);


                File file = new File(newFolder, imageName);

                if (file.exists()) file.delete();
                try
                {
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                    imagenObtenida.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    int imagenObtenidaW = imagenObtenida.getWidth();
                    int imagenObtenidaH = imagenObtenida.getHeight();
                    Log.e("imagenObtenidaW " ," = +" + imagenObtenidaW + " imagenObtenidaH = " + imagenObtenidaH);

                } catch (Exception e) {

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: My image viewer says that's not a valid PNG file.  The `file` utility identifies it as JPEG.

Comment: options.inSampleSize = 2; -- the docs say -- If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.  ---- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html

Comment: @Tasos You should post that as an answer.

Comment: i gave my answer try that way and let me know is it working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options.inSampleSize = 2;
```

the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) say -- If set to a value > 1, requests the decoder to subsample the original image, returning a smaller image to save memory.

so try setting that to 1 and see if it helps

Comment: But not the original picture. Better do not use Bitmap and BitmapFactory to download files.

Answer (score 1):

It happens, because here you are using option property of `BitmapFacotory` option `inSampleSize`. When you use `inSampleSize = 2`, then your image will become **1/2 of original height and width**. So, for maintaining original size you need to set it to `1`, or just remove it and pass as `null` in `decodeStream` function.

Answer (score 0):

Why didn't you use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead of writing custom code, Please have a look it's quite simple and powerful library so far.

Answer (score 0):

try this way and for more just follow it http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimage, options);
    int imageHeight = options.outHeight;
    int imageWidth = options.outWidth;
    String imageType = options.outMimeType;
```

**OR**

Aquery is also using for image loading, download aquery jar and import it in your project and try this way

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ImageView img;
    private AQuery aq;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        aq = new AQuery(this);
        img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.simpleLoadImg);
        aq.id(R.id.simpleLoadImg).image("103.24.4.60/CLASSNK1/MobileService.svc/DownloadFile/FileName/3_20150928162252018.png",false,false);

    }


}
```